# How to validate SAML response

Tags: single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

I create SAML application on my Okta dashboard. Now when I clicked on that application it redirect me to my site and on my site I got SAML response.

What I need to do is to check that request is valid or not. If the request is valid, I'll skip my login page and let user login automatically.

How can I make sure the request is valid? I develop that code in MVC C#.

Answer (score 1):

Which SAML toolkit are you using? In case if you are using Kentor you can see this article http://developer.okta.com/blog/2016/03/22/use-kentor-authservices-with-Okta which uses example app to validate SAML response. If you are using another toolkit you would need to check its documentation as how to validate SAML response, as toolkits vary in configuration and are 3rd party tools.

You would need certificate from Okta, which you can download from your app by going to the sign on tab and click view setup tab and download the certificate from the page that will be used to validate SAML.

Comment: Thanks Sohaib, I use okta music share http://developer.okta.com/code/dotnet/sample_application.html

Comment: I download certificate from okta and validate it by signedXml.CheckSignature(certificate.cert, true); that code. Now i encrypt that response ASE256-CBC algorithm and key transport is RSA-OAED. Can you tell how to decrypt that response and where did i get Private key to decrypt.

Comment: Music store is the example application. But which SAML toolkit are you using?

Comment: I am using SAML 2.0.

Comment: Which toolkit for SAML 2.0. For example, for .NET there is Kentor, for PHP there is SimpleSAMLPhp etc.

Comment: I use Okta.Core

Comment: I refer Kentor example. But I want to know how to validate response when user click on saml app from his okta dashboard and he redirected to my website. Also how can I encrypt and decrypt that response.

Comment: You need to consult Kentor documentation for this as it is SP side configuration.